# glut camera makes rectangles lean

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm making a simple game. This is in 2d, but the gluLookAt is 3d (with z position), is there anyway I can get a 2d representation of this without the perspective changing the way the world works?

[image: pic related]

If any of you want to know, this all works with the players position.

```
gluLookAt(jake.px, 0.0f, jake.pz + 20, jake.px, 7.0f, jake.pz, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
```

Platforms drawn with:

```
void drawPlatform (Platform* p, GLuint texture){
    float x = p->px, y = p->py, z = p->pz, w = p->width, h = p->height;
    drawCircle(x, y, 0.1f, 80);
    //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glColor3f(0, 1.0f, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        //glTexCoord2f(x, y);

        glVertex2f(x, y + h);
        //glTexCoord2f(x, y + h);

        glVertex2f(x + w, y + h);
        //glTexCoord2f(x + w, y + h);

        glVertex2f(x + w, y);
        //glTexCoord2f(x + w, y);
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're using the 3D perspective functions (gluLookAt with gluPerspective) when you want 2D ones. Use [glOrtho](http://stackoverflow.com/a/734329/21475) instead :-)

Comment: @Cameron yeah, but will that allow me to change the X, and Y position of the camera?

Comment: Sure, just set the left/right/top/bottom accordingly when you call the function. Alternatively, draw everything relative to the camera's logical position, and keep the camera's actual position at (0, 0). This will avoid floating point errors at far distances.

Comment: @Cameron sounds good but now I can't find where to position to display all my platforms xD